# How many type of subsets including 0 or not including 0 in a combination of (n+1, k+1)?

Tags: combinatorics

Given the set of $n+1$ integers $\{0,1,2,....,n\}$ and count the combinations consisting of $k+1$ distinct elements from this set. The combination is then $n+1 \choose k+1$.

Among these subsets, some include $0$ and others do not. How many are there of each type?

The way I'm trying to work this is to think in binary in terms of either there's $0$ or not.
So would it be a case of power sets?

Comment: If it doesn't include $0$, it's a subset of size $k+1$ of some other set- can you see what set? If it includes $0$, then if you take out the $0$ it's a subset of size $k$ of some other set.

Comment: Do you mean with the $0$ it's a subset of size $k+1$ and without, $k$?

Comment: No. If we start with a subset of size $k+1$ and it doesn't have $0$, then it's still a subset of size $0$. If we start with a subset of size $k+1$, but it has $0$ and then we take it out, then we have a subset of size $k$. The trick is to note that the collection of all size $k+1$ subsets of $\{0,1...n\}$ without $0$ is equal to the collection of all size $k+1$ subsets of [something else]. Also, that the collection of size $k+1$ subsets of $\{0,1...n\}$ with $0$, and then taking $0$ out of all of those subsets is equal to the collection of size $k$ subsets of [something else].